# How to “validate” a .mcpack

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]

It says that I have to “validate” my .mcpack.I don’t know how 2 do stuff like this plz help
Anyone’s help will be very deeply appreciated. I downloaded it off of Minecraft curse forge. It is supposed to be a world edit mod. I rly want it 2 work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot validate it as the problem is that the mcpack is 'not a valid zip archive'. This usually means that it is corrupted or incompletely downloaded.

Try to download / reinstall again.

If you have made the resource pack yourself, [this forum user suggests that you make sure that](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-discussion/2754620-behavior-packs-fail-to-import?comment=3):

1. In your manifest.json...Make sure you have created a new UUID for each of the Pack_ID and UUID fields. Create a different one for each.
2. Make sure to remove any .json behavior files that you haven't changed. This is also good form.
3. Make sure you Zip the contents of the behavior folder with manifest.json as the root file in the zip
4. Remove the dependency section of the manifest.json if the behavior doesn't have a resource pack dependency. If it does, make sure it matches the resource pack UUID, not the Pack_ID.